# Hooking up a local VS2012.2 project back up to tfs-git

Tags: visual-studio-2012, git-tfs

I'm having difficulty searching for the exact answer to my question. Apologies if its been asked many times.

I've been developing on Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 for some time and having changes tracked and saved in a TFS-GIT repository, alongside the equivalent local repo stored on my hard disk.

About two weeks ago, my laptop got stolen. I've got all my tools back onto a new laptop but struggling with getting my project back the way I had it before it got stolen.

Essentially, I can see the Visual Studio Project locally on my hard drive, with its local git history. I can also see the remote version in TFS, with the exact same history. I open the project locally on my visual studio, and then try to connect to the remote tfs store. When the project loads, all of the files and folders within the project have the pending delete symbol (red cross) on each of the files, as if the remote connection has gone in a folder to high and the two structures are out of sync with each other.

Can anyone help me with how to connect the two together again properly

Comment: I added the `git-tfs` tag to your question, although it's unclear whether you meant `git-tfs`, `git-tf` or just plain `git`...  Please clarify your question if I didn't understand...!

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure to understand your problem (and to know if you are using git-tfs). What are you really want to do? use git-tfs to work and commit on TFS? or use TFS but use git-tfs as a backup solution?
Anyway, I will try to give you some tips.

> Essentially, I can see the Visual Studio Project locally on my hard
>   drive, with its local git history.

If that's the case, you only have to open your solution, work and create local git commits.
After, you only have to the TFS server.
Perhaps, you could bootstrap your local git repository if you were using git-tfs (but not 100% sure you need it) by :

```
git tfs bootsrap
```

To commit on a TFS server, use :

```
git tfs rcheckin
```

And that should be all...

> I open the project locally on my visual studio, and then try to connect to the remote tfs store.

If you are using git-tfs, you don't have to. Git-tfs use its own workspace in a hidden directory of the .git folder.

Hope it will help. Even if there is not enough informations to provide a good answer.

Feel free to use the wiki for more informations :
https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/wiki/Bootstrap
https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/wiki

PS : if you are using git-tfs, don't install the "Git Source Control Provider" because you can't open a git repository in Visual Studio and in the same time connect on a TFS server to get builds result, workitems, ...